# How to run a Ruby project on localhost and web simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost

I am presently developing a web service using Ruby on Rails. I wish to run it on LAN as well as web simultaneously? How can it be done?

Comment: Just make sure your server accepts requests both from the outside web and your LAN.  The Rails application shouldn't care where the request originates from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming

- You want you want to demonstrate a product running on a local machine to a person on the internet.

OR

- You are trying to test Paypal IPN notification.

**1)** Install the [proxylocal](http://proxylocal.com/) gem

```
gem install proxylocal
```

**2)** Run your rails server in development mode.

**3)** Run proxy local

```
$ proxylocal 3000 --host joshi_server
Local server on port 3000 is now publicly available via:
http://joshi_server.t.proxylocal.com/
```

Now, you can access your local server using `http://joshi_server.t.proxylocal.com/`  anywhere from the web.

**Note**

**Similar services**

*Free* : [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/), [pagekite](https://pagekite.net/), [yaler](http://www.yaler.org/),

*Paid* : [showoff.io](https://showoff.io/)

I found `proxylocal`, `localtunnel`, and `showoff` to be similar w.r.t ease of use and reliability. I prefer `proxylocal` as it allows me to name and reuse the subdomain for my local server.

**Do not use this approach for a production setup**

Comment: actually im developing an intranet system which would be running on our college's server. but i want to make sure that the users should be able to access it from their home through internet as well.

Comment: Why don't you use a service like Heroku? You can access the servers anywhere and you will be able to get the service up and running without too much hassle.

Comment: can it do https ?

Comment: You can use  https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 1):

Either allow the access to the server via LAN and Internet OR setup two servers that point to the same database. Rails starts multiple instances anyway, so you will not have corrupt data.

Comment: you are saying that i should deploy it on haraku as well as on my lan sever? how can it be done?

Comment: Yeah. You just checkout your rails app to both servers. Then you allow access to your db from remote clients. Then you change the database.yml accordingly. On haraku it would be localhost on your local machine you need to specify an IP or a domain. You should search for a howto if you are not sure how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "how can I make my local webserver also accessible from the general internet" then the easy way to get started is to establish an SSH tunnel from a suitable remote host, such as a VPS or other server, to your local machine.

You will need to ensure that your `sshd` configuration permits open tunnel ports, as by default these are restricted.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how can I call my localhost from the internet? How is it done?